# Set 3 values in an array - dynamic table row javascrip

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamic table and when i add a row i want to save the data from input.

I can save the data but all inside one array,i want to set just 3 values each sub array.

Because one row have 3 inputs.

But i´m having some difficulties.

I'm new to javascript and here at stack overflow

Can you help me please?

```js
function arraySaveData() {

    var data = [];

    for (var index = 0; index < 1; index++) {

        $('#mytableform1').each(function (_, element) {

            var element = document.getElementsByName("namesavedata[]");

            for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {

                data.push(element[i].value);
            }

        });

        
        var result = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var obj = {}

            obj= data[i];

            result.push(obj)

        }
        console.log(result)

    }

}


//Button add table row 
function addRow() {

    var table = document.getElementById("mytableform1");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    x = document.getElementById("mytableform1").rows.length;

    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    //numeração crescente
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="namesavedata[]" align="center" placeholder="' +
            (cell1.innerHTML = i + 0) +
            '">';

        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="namesavedata[]" align="center" placeholder="00000,000">';

        cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="namesavedata[]" align="center" placeholder="00000,000">';

    }
}
//Button delete table row 
function deleteRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytableform1");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    if (rowCount >= 4) {
        table.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
    } else {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Erro!',
            text: "Não pode apagar este campo",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#e55353',
            cancelButtonColor: '#636f83',
            confirmButtonText: 'ok'
        })
    }

}
```

```html
<table id="mytableform1" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 1px solid;color: #5c6873;background-color: #fff;border-color: #e4e7ea;">
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top">Vértices da poligonal</td>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top">Coordenadas no sistema PT -  TM06/ETRS89</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">M(m)</td>
      <td align="center" valign="top">P(m)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr name="allDataRow">
      <td align="center" valign="top">
         <input style="width: 100%;" class="form-control" type="number" name="namesavedata[]" id="val_1" placeholder="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
         <input style="width: 100%;" class="form-control" type="number" name="namesavedata[]" id="val_2" placeholder="00000,000">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
         <input style="width: 100%;" class="form-control" type="number" name="namesavedata[]" id="val_3" placeholder="00000,000">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div style="display:flex;justify-content: space-between;">
   <div style="display:flex;">
      <button onclick="addRow()" style="background-color: #673ab7c7;color: white;" class="btn" type="button">
      <span class="bi bi-plus-square-dotted"></span>+
      </button>
      <button onclick="deleteRow()" style="background-color: #673ab7c7;color: white;" class="btn" type="button">
      <span class="bi bi-plus-square-dotted"></span>-
      </button>
   </div>
   <div style="display:flex;">
      <button type="button" name="button" onclick="arraySaveData()" class="btn" style="background-color: #673ab7c7;color: white;">
      Validar dados da tabela
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what does your dynamic table actually look like then? Are _all_ the input fields named just `namesavedata[]`? You could either write code that loops over the actual table rows first, and then processes the fields in each one; or just fill your array the way you currently do, and then just "chunk" that resulting array into an array of sub-arrays containing three elements each.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation, i just put the all code with the dynamic table

Comment: now my array it's receiving the data, but just in one array. what i want is to set three elements in subarrays but im having dificults. Im very new at javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are creating an object and then reassigning it to the value of data[i]. This is then being pushed to your array, rather than an object, so you are getting an array of values rather than an array of objects.

Change this line of code:

```
var obj = {};
obj = data[i];
result.push(obj); // Add data[i] to the results array.
```

To this:

```
var obj = {data[i]};
result.push(obj); // Add an object containing data[i] to the results array
```

Now, you are pushing the object with the value of data[i] inside.

Or if you want to have three sub-arrays as in your question:

```
var tableCell = [data[i]];
result.push(tableCell);
```

If you run this code snippet, you can see what's happening when you reassign obj to data[i]:

```
const data = ["foo","bar"];
var obj = {};

console.log(obj);
// output: {}

obj = data[0];

console.log(obj);
// output: "foo"
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized what my mistake was. It works now, i just need to set 3 objects inside the array now